# Filtering on Django Queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

So, I think I am missing something very obvious, or setup my models incorrectly, I am attempting to create a view on my blog that filters on the category slug, but my filter will only work on the Entry slug; please see my models below as well as my views.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

**My Models**

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django_markdown.models import MarkdownField


class EntryQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def published(self):
        return self.filter(publish=True)


class Tag(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.slug


class Category(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.slug


class Entry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = MarkdownField()
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    publish = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)

    objects = EntryQuerySet.as_manager()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("post_detail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Blog Entry"
        verbose_name_plural = "Blog Entries"
        ordering = ["-created"]
```

**My Views**

```
from django.views import generic
from . import models


class BlogIndex(generic.ListView):
    queryset = models.Entry.objects.published()
    template_name = "blog/post_list.html"


class BlogDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = models.Entry
    template_name = "blog/post_detail.html"


# Marketing Pages
class GlamisView(generic.ListView):
    queryset = models.Entry.objects.filter(slug="glamis")
    template_name = "blog/glamis_list.html"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you right you can use a lookup expression. Your query will look like:

```
queryset = models.Entry.objects.filter(category__slug="glamis")
```

[More on querying many to one relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/)

Comment: That worked!!  I tried that initially but didn't realize the double underscore.  Thank you!